# Can't get Spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I have a Spring project in which I want to get a specific Spring bean defined in my Spring beans XML File. My Spring bean XML file is located at `/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml`.

Here is my code in the Service class:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");
```

Here is the error I get when I compile :

```
parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably WEB-INF is not inside your classpath. I suggest to move the xml file in the classpath (for example `src/main/resources/spring/root-context.xml`). Then you can access it with: `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/root-context.xml");` If you're inside web application, Spring Mvc looks for th context in `WEB-INF/<the name of the dispatcher servlet>-servlet.xml`

If you want to access the context from WEB-INF you can load it using

```
  GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
  XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
  xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource(path));
```

A better way is using `WebApplicationContextUtils` or implement `ApplicationContextAware`. Not sure what your use case is...

Comment: Yes I know, but what I want is that my XML file that is in web-inf can be accessed from both MVC layer and simple Service layers classes using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext . Is there a way to do this ?